# Windbg command's each result as parameter in script

Tags: windbg

I intend to search opcodes in specific memory area in process's dump.

I want to have some conditions while searching.

like:
$$><<>script.wds #call 00400000 L? 01000000

```
for(00400000 ~ 01000000)
{
    // this condition is if argument's opcode which is address is not in this area 
   .if(arg1's opcode !in 00400000 ~ 01000000)
      .print arg1
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's pseudo-code, not a real WinDbg script, is it?

Comment: yes it's example of what I'm intended to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`#`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566244(v=vs.85).aspx), [`.foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563124(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`$spat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552157(v=vs.85).aspx).

Lets say you want to find the few first `call` opcodes in `notepad!WinMain`. You could do something like this:

```
0:000> .foreach (addr {# call notepad!WinMain L20}) { .if ($spat("addr", "notepad!*:")) {.echo addr} }
notepad!WinMain+0xa:
notepad!WinMain+0x19:
notepad!WinMain+0x20:
notepad!WinMain+0x33:
notepad!WinMain+0x39:
notepad!WinMain+0x45:
```

And now the explanation.

`# call notepad!WinMain L20` searches for the string "call" in the disassembly on the specified range. This is the output:

```
0:000> # call notepad!WinMain L20
notepad!WinMain+0xa:
01002940 ff1514110001    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetCommandLineW (01001114)]
notepad!WinMain+0x19:
0100294f ff151c120001    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetSystemMetrics (0100121c)]
notepad!WinMain+0x20:
01002956 ff1510110001    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetProcAddress (01001110)]
notepad!WinMain+0x33:
01002969 ffd0            call    eax
notepad!WinMain+0x39:
0100296f e874f2ffff      call    notepad!SkipProgramName (01001be8)
notepad!WinMain+0x45:
0100297b e8e51b0000      call    notepad!NPInit (01004565)
```

The `.foreach (var {cmd}) {commands}` executes *cmd*, splits the output at whitespaces, and executes *{commands}* once for each of the tokens it got with "*var*" being replaced with that token.

Without the `.if` we'd get something like:

```
0:000> .foreach (addr {# call notepad!WinMain L20}) {.echo addr}
notepad!WinMain+0xa:
01002940
ff1514110001
call
dword
ptr
[notepad!_imp__GetCommandLineW
(01001114)]
notepad!WinMain+0x19:
0100294f
ff151c120001
call
dword
ptr
[notepad!_imp__GetSystemMetrics
 .
 .
 .
```

Finally we add the `.if` to check whether our token starts with "*notepad!*" and ends with "*:*". Note that we have to test for the colon at the end. Otherwise we might get "*notepad!SkipProgramName*" and "*notepad!NPInit*". Even testing for "*notepad!WinMain**" isn't enough, since it might be the target of local jumps.

---

Now, if you want to pass this address to any command, you have to get rid of the colon at the end of the *addr* alias the `.foreach` command created. I'm not sure there's even a way to do it, so we do one last trick. Every time we find and *addr* that fits the pattern we set a flag, and at every iteration we check the flag. If the flag is raised, we use the current token. Since the output of `#` is of the form

```
Symbol:
address opcode_byte opcode_mnemonic argument ...
```

The token following the symbol that matches our pattern is a clean address.

For example, the following command disassembles two opcode for each `call` found:

```
0:000> .foreach (addr {# call notepad!WinMain L20}) { .if (@$t0==1) { u addr L2; r @$t0=0;}; .if ($spat("addr", "notepad!*:")) { r @$t0 = 1} }
notepad!WinMain+0xa:
01002940 ff1514110001    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetCommandLineW (01001114)]
01002946 68d8130001      push    offset notepad!`string' (010013d8)
notepad!WinMain+0x19:
0100294f ff151c120001    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetSystemMetrics (0100121c)]
01002955 50              push    eax
notepad!WinMain+0x20:
01002956 ff1510110001    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetProcAddress (01001110)]
0100295c 33f6            xor     esi,esi
notepad!WinMain+0x33:
01002969 ffd0            call    eax
0100296b ff7514          push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
notepad!WinMain+0x39:
0100296f e874f2ffff      call    notepad!SkipProgramName (01001be8)
01002974 50              push    eax
notepad!WinMain+0x45:
0100297b e8e51b0000      call    notepad!NPInit (01004565)
01002980 85c0            test    eax,eax
```

(The pseudo-register `$t0` is the flag.)

And now, after this horror is done I join [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4136325/thomas) in suggesting you use [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) if you want to go even a further beyond that.

The mere fact that we **can** do this using WinDbg's awful awful scripting language doesn't mean that we **should**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understood what you need, but I think it is similar to the following.

Create a script which does what you want, using pseudo registers, e.g.

```
.for(r @$t2=@$t0; @$t2<@$t1; r @$t2=@$t2+1) {.printf "%d, ", @$t2}
```

Set up the "parameters" in pseudo registers

```
0:000> r @$t0 = 0x4
0:000> r @$t1 = 0x10
```

Then run the script:

```
0:000> $$>< script.wds
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
```

Considering the whole task, I'd not recommend doing that in plain WinDbg and use some higher level abstraction such as [PyKD](https://pykd.codeplex.com/), because

- it's not easy to [get the opcode from an ASM statement](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6637/windbg-how-to-determine-the-opcode-for-an-assembly-language-instruction-or-set)
- you might want to search in `!address`es only that are `PAGE_EXECUTE`
- WinDbg scripts are often cryptic and not very maintainable

Answer (score 0):

your query is unclear do you want to do something like this

```
0:000> .shell -ci ".echo"  type c:\foo.txt
# ${$arg1} ${$arg2} ${$arg3}.shell: Process exited
```

running the above script by providing three arguments you can search for 
any instruction in the range you provide 
the argument 1 is call so i want to search for call instructions
arg 2 is an expression  therefor windbg will be evaluated to an address like 0x12340000 
arg 3 again is an expression evaluated to size 
result as follows

```
0:000> $$>a< c:\foo.txt call windbg L900
windbg+0x1009:
01341009 e8340170e8      call    e9a41142
windbg+0x10b5:
013410b5 e834010000      call    windbg+0x11ee (013411ee)
windbg+0x1171:
01341171 e8000060e8      call    e9941176
```