# Search the entire code for a specific call instruction with windbg

Tags: windbg

Is it possible to search the entire executable memory space to find all the places from which a specific method is called? For example I want to find all functions from where MyApplcation!MyFunction is called. Searching for a specific optcode with "s" command is not an option as in my case call command uses relative code path so optcode is different depending on where call instruction itself is located.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windbg command's each result as parameter in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471840/windbg-commands-each-result-as-parameter-in-script)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**0:000> lm m calc**

```
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
005f0000 006b0000   calc       (pdb symbols)          e:\symbols\calc.pdb
\971D2945E998438C847643A9DB39C88E2\calc.pdb
```

**0:000> $$ lets search who all calls the operator new function within calc memory space**

```
0:000> # op*new 5f0000 l?(6b0000-5f0000)
```

output

```
calc!WinMain+0x213:
005f17e7 e89a0a0000      call    calc!operator new (005f2286)
calc!WinMain+0x272:
005f1843 e83e0a0000      call    calc!operator new (005f2286)
calc!operator new+0x26:
005f229d 0f84fcb80200    je      calc!operator new+0x11 (0061db9f)
calc!operator new[]+0x26:
005f32b1 0f8438a90200    je      calc!operator new[]+0x11 (0061dbef)
calc!CCalculatorState::storeAndFire+0x7:
005f33c9 e83becffff      call    calc!operator new (005f2009)
calc!CCalculatorState::storeAndFire+0x76:
005f3437 e84aeeffff      call    calc!operator new (005f2286)
calc!CCalculatorState::storeAndFire+0x8a:
005f3447 e83aeeffff      call    calc!operator new (005f2286)
calc!CUIController::UpdateTwoLineDisplay+0x56:
005f35c7 e8cefcffff      call    calc!operator new[] (005f329a)
calc!ATL::CAutoVectorPtr<ATL::CAtlREMatchContext<ATL::CAtlRECharTraitsW>::MatchGroup>::Allocate+0x7:
005f3a8c e81ae8ffff      call    calc!operator new+0x30 (005f22ab)
calc!ATL::CAutoVectorPtr<ATL::CAtlREMatchContext<ATL::CAtlRECharTraitsW>::MatchGroup>::Allocate+0x27:
005f3aac e8e9f7ffff      call    calc!operator new[] (005f329a)
calc!ATL::CAtlREMatchContext<ATL::CAtlRECharTraitsW>::CAtlREMatchContext<ATL::CAtlRECharTraitsW>+0x7:
005f3b52 e8b2e4ffff      call    calc!operator new (005f2009)
calc!ATL::CAutoVectorPtr<void *>::Allocate+0x7:
```

Comment: @conio i rollbacked your edit because $ is an operator in windbg for inline commenting  $ rollback $ whatever foo $ omg will insert that comment inline in windbg command window please look into windbg docs substituting # in place of 0:000> $ xxxxxxxxxxxxx is not correct edit

Comment: Sorry. It wasn't part of the single space block so I guessed it was a typo. (And if you really meant a comment inside the WinDbg prompt, I think you need two Dollar signs. Please look into Windbg docs.)

Comment: Just minor addition: Even though the docs say to use `L Size` syntax for `#` command, it does accept the regular range syntax of WinDbg. So instead of doing "end address - begin address" math there, one can drop the `L` and just put end address as in `# op*new 5f0000 6b0000` (Tested in version 10.0.19041.685)

Comment: The question was regarding specific call for MyApplcation!MyFunction but your answer seems to provide a solution to find all uses of new operator within the entire dll, no?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to above answer just elaborating on how to find the text segment start and size.

```
!dh -f abc.exe
0000000140000000 image base

!dh -s abc.exe
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
  124D6A virtual size
    1000 virtual address
  124E00 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data

Add RVA of .text 1000 to image base 140000000 and dissemble the entire text segment
u 140001000 L124D6A

Or
Use # command to find the function in the disassembly
# GetSimpleProtocol 140001000 L124D6A
```